# Convergence of series $n/(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have some problems to determine the sum of the following series, 
$$ \sum \limits^{\propto }_{n=1}\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} =\frac{1}{4}  $$
appreciation or appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try writing out the partial fraction expansion? And then seeing if terms 'telescope' and cancel?

Comment: Have you tried a partial fraction decomposition? Please post any attempts you have made so far.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

observe that $$\frac n{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac1{n+3} -\frac{1/2}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1/2}{(n+2)(n+3)} $$ is  a telescoping series of the form $a_n = u_n - u_{n+1}$  where $u_n = \frac1{n+2}-\frac{1/2}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$  then $$ a_1+a_2 + \cdots = (u_1 -u_2) + (u_2-u_3) + \cdots=u_1-u_\infty = \frac13 - \frac1{12}=\frac1{4} $$

Comment: Thank you, i very appreciate.

Comment: @user239295, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{-3}{2(n+3)}+\frac{2}{n+2}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2(2)}-\frac{1}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{-3}{2(n+3)}+\frac{2}{n+3}-\frac{1}{2(n+3)}=\frac{1}{4}$$