# Compute using the telescoping series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-fractions, telescopic-series

This question is similarly found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316250/convergence-of-series-n-n1n2n3), and I have been trying to break it down using partial fraction however I cannot seem to get the final result as in the thread linked. I would very much appreciate some advice on my solution!

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac{1}{4}$

I have tried splitting this into Partial fractions:

$$n = \frac{A}{(n+2)(n+3)}+\frac{B}{(n+1)(n+3)}+\frac{C}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

when n = 1 I find that A = $\frac{1}{12}$; When n = 2 then B = $\frac{2}{15}$; and when n = 3 then C = $\frac{3}{17}$

This then gets me:

$$\frac{(1/12)}{(n+1)}+\frac{(2/15)}{(n+2)}+\frac{(3/17)}{(n+3)}$$

However, I cannot seem to derive the solution $\frac{1}{4}$ from this.

Comment: Some of those coefficients should have been negative. Also, that's an odd way to set up the partial fractions, usually we put a single linear factor in each denominator, not two of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have computed the partial fractions incorrectly. If we write
$$\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac A{n+1} + \frac B{n+2} + \frac C{n+3}$$
then this rearranges as
$$n = A(n+2)(n+3) + B(n+1)(n+3) + C(n+1)(n+2)$$
and we need to plug in $n = -1, -2, -3$. Setting $n = -1$ gives us $A = -\frac12$, setting $n = -2$ gives us $B=2$, and setting $n = -3$ gives us $C = -\frac32$, so

\begin{align}
\frac{n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}
 & = -\frac{1/2}{n+1} + \frac{2}{n+2} - \frac{3/2}{n+3}\\ 
 & = -\frac{1/2}{n+1} + \frac{1/2}{n+2} + \frac{3/2}{n+2} - \frac{3/2}{n+3} \\
 & = \dfrac12\left(\dfrac{1}{n+2}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)+\dfrac32\left(\dfrac{1}{n+2}-\dfrac{1}{n+3}\right)
\end{align}

and now the telescoping is more clear (this is the same form as in E.H.E.'s answer in the post you linked).

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question and uploaded the picture of the solution.
Steps:
1.You need to write numerator as 2*(1/2)
2.Write 2 as (n+3)-(n+1)
3.Then separate it into partial fractions.
4. After that write the series and the club the terms which are common in both the partial fractions.
5. After that again decompose n/[(n+1)(n+2)] as 1/(n+1) - 1/(n+2).
6. Write the series and you are left with 1/(2*2), which is 1/4.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbnX9.jpg)

Comment: Why do you write 2 as $(n+3)-(n+1)$?

Comment: Since many of the times in telescoping series, you need to express numerator in terms of denominator terms so that some of the terms will get canceled out.

Comment: Aha! I see the trick now, thanks!